# PHP - Get timestamp X hours from now

Tags: php, time, countdown

I'd like to take a number of hours imputed in a text box and get a timestamp back so I can create a countdown timer.

The countdown is fine so ignore how that is done etc. But whats the best way to get a timestamp '48' hours from now. For example user has entered `48`?

Comment: Google "datetime add hours php" which you may very well land on one of [**John Conde's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228865/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hours = 48;
$timestamp = (new DateTime())->modify("+{$hours} hours")->format('U');
```

Comment: [`I plugged ya`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389744/php-get-timestamp-x-hours-from-now#comment37722862_24389744) ;-)

Comment: You shot me? ;) Didn't realize it was a dupe. Closing this one as a dupe of the other one.

Comment: Au contraire mon frère. Around here, "to plug" means to "tell people of one's good work" ;-) http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plug *"a free advertisement or a commercial boost from someone for a product. (See also plugola.) : I managed to get a plug on the Mike Michael show.
tv."*

Comment: I knew what you meant. I guess being Italian and from New York the other one always springs to mind. :)

Comment: *Holding up Wile E. Coyote's **YIPES!** sign*

Comment: Thanks. I did search but as the answer was out of my mind set I missed that you could  just `+ X hours`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a timestamp like this:

```
<?php
strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "+ 48 hours");
?>
```

Comment: Does that take Daylight savings into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for [strtotime](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php). For example, you can just use `strtotime('+48 hours')`, and it will return a unix timestamp for that time.